# Hadoop how to delete data on disk after reformatted namenode

Tags: hadoop, format

I want to know that Hadoop how to process disk data after reformatted namenode.
 The namenode stores metasore of clusters , In HDFS data from disk data mapping.
when reformatting namenode , hadoop how to execute deletion of disk data?
  I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you reformat namenode, all the data in namenode is deleted and your namenode becomes fresh. It will be given a new cluster id. All the other nodes are now having old cluster id. So its always a bad idea to reformat namenode when cluster is active .
If you do this accidentally you need to restore namenode metadata from secondary namenode. 
If u want to delete data in your data nodes you can simply execute `hadoop hdfs -rm -R /`